# Str_replace multiple strings in one variable?

Tags: php

How can I combine the two str_replace to one variable?

```
$putbhp = str_replace("cc,A","cc,0bhp,A",$whites);

$putbhp = str_replace("cc,M","cc,0bhp,M",$whites);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$putbhp = str_replace(['cc,A', 'cc,M'], ['cc,0bhp,A', 'cc,0bhp,M'], $whites);
```

If you're stuck with an old version of PHP (< 5.4), substitute the array shorthand with `array('val', 'val', 'etc')`

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/3HKxV9